# How to share objects in c++ across libraries

Tags: c++, object, logging, gtk, gtkmm

Suppose I have a program like this:

#### File main.cpp

```cpp
#include "something.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    some = new Something();
    return 0;
}
```

which will be linked to a .so library consisting of following files:

#### File logger.hpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Logger {
    public:
        Logger();
        void log(char);
        void set_name(char);
    private:
        char m_name;
};
```

#### File logger.cpp

```cpp
#include "logger.hpp"

Logger::Logger() {}
void Logger::log(char msg) {
     std::cout << this->m_name << " : " << msg;
}
void Logger::set_name(char name) {
    this->m_name = name;
}
```

#### File something.hpp

```cpp
#include "logger.hpp"

class Something {
    public:
        Something();
};
```

#### File something.cpp

```cpp
#include "something.hpp"

Something::Something() {
    logger->log("hello !");
}
```

The code as it is now will fail in `something.cpp` at `logger->log()`, because `logger` has never been defined. I could solve this by adding `logger = new Logger()`. But I want to only create a new `Logger` instance, if none has been created in a program / library using this library. When an instance has been created already, I can use that by adding `extern Logger logger;`. But this will not work, when *no* instance has been created. Any suggestions (is it possible at all ?) ?

Note: I am using Gtkmm4 / Glibmm2.6 already, maybe there is a solution by using Gtk or Glib ...

Comment: "But i want to only create a new Logger instance, if none has been created..." - This sounds like the Singleton design pattern, unless I do not understand your question correctly?

Comment: @BobMorane you __did__ understand correctly

Comment: Ok, then since you seem to have control over the logger class, maybe you should [make it a singleton](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1098119). If you do this, beware though that sigletons also have the side effect of allowing global access. However, in the case of a logger, this might be ok.

Comment: Thank you @BobMorane for pointing me in the right direction as always ;) But, will a singleton be available across different libraries / programs ?

Comment: What do you mean? If the logger is its library, simply link to it to use it. Unless you have other considerations?

Comment: You might want to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623657/multiple-instances-of-singleton-across-shared-libraries-on-linux) as well if using this pattern.

Comment: @BobMorane i mean, in the same library there is definition and implementation of the logger and definition and implementation of something that uses the logger. But the logger may be used in the program that uses the library, too, and the program and the something class / instance should both be using the same instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First approach: Singleton

As discussed in the comments, you could use the [Singleton design pattern](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1098119)
to acheive this. However, remember that this pattern has [several drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons),
two of which are:

- Singletons allow global access.
- Singletons are hard to unit test.

Which are true problems when writing quality software. Also, for your particular
case, make sure to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623657/multiple-instances-of-singleton-across-shared-libraries-on-linux) which explains how to make sure everything
is linked appropriately so you do not end up with multiple instances of your
singleton.

## Second approach: dependency injection

I decided to post an answer here to illustrate another way of doing things that
solves the two issues mentionned above: [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) (DI). With DI,
you do not create your dependencies, you inject them through parameters. For
example, instead of:

```cpp
Something::Something() {
    auto logger = new Logger(); // Dependency creation (not injection)
    logger->log("hello !");
}
```

you would have something like:

```cpp
Something::Something(Logger* p_logger) { // Logger dependency injected through p_logger
    p_logger->log("hello !");
}
```

*Note that DI does not solve the "one instance" issue by itself*. Care must be taken to
create your dependencies once (usually in your `main`) and then pass them around as
parameters to use them. However, the global access issue is resolved.

You can bring this to another level by abstracting your dependencies. For example,
you could write an interface to your `Logger` class and use this instead:

```cpp
// Somewhere in your library:
class ILogger
{
public:
    virtual ~ILogger() = default;
    virtual void log(const std::string& p_message) = 0;
    virtual void set_name(const std::string& p_name) = 0;
};

// In Logger.hpp:
class Logger : public ILogger {
    public:
        Logger();

        void log(const std::string& p_message) override;
        void set_name(const std::string& p_name) override;

    private:
        std::string m_name;
};

// In something.hpp/cpp:
Something::Something(ILogger* p_logger) { // Logger dependency injected through p_logger
    p_logger->log("hello !");
}
```

To acheive this your `main` could look like this:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Here, you create your logger dependency:
    std::unique_ptr<ILogger> concreteLogger = std::make_unique<Logger>();
    concreteLogger->set_name("frederic");

    // Here, you inject it. From here on, you will inject it everywhere
    // in your code. The using code will have no idea that under the hood,
    // you really are using the Logger implementation:
    some = new Something(concreteLogger.get());

    // Note: if you use `new`, do not forget to use `delete` as well. Otherwise,
    //       check out std::unique_ptr, like above.

    return 0;
}
```

The advantage of this is that you can now change the implementation of your logger
at any time whithout anything (except `main`) caring about it. You can also create
mocks of your logger in case you want to unit test `Something`. This is highly
more flexible that handling the singleton in your unit tests, which in term will
create all sorts of (hard to investigate/resolve) problems. This, in terms, solves
the second issue mentionned above.

Note that a possible drawback of DI is that you may end up having lots of
parameters, but in my opinion it is still superior to using singletons.

Comment: I think this should become a community wiki answer, because there may be others with the same problem

Comment: If i want to add a destructor, should i make it private or public ?

Comment: In the Logger class?

Comment: i mean, whenever i implement a singleton, should the destructor be private like the constructor, or public like the instance method

Comment: I think you can make it public. Also, if you are using C++11, you could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) out.

Comment: i am even using C++17